# Opening AdMob Account

Tags: android, admob, adsense

I am trying to publish my app for the first time. If I am not wrong, in order to put admob ad to my application, I should have an admob account.

1. **My question is do I need to open the admob account with the same gmail account that I used to open my play store developers account?**
2. **I watch some tutorial on how to integrate admob to your app from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qsjT93LNnGY), in 5:00min there is AdUnit Id, for that, if my my application is not yet publish, then, I should follow the instruction as given [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ram0OY-FAdU) from 5:00min (selecting Add app manually), right?**

Edit:

From [here](http://www.appsbaba.com/android/android-app-monetization/get-new-admob-payment-india-eftwire-transfer/) its written,
**"Therefore developers need an Adsense account to get payment from New Admob."**

3. How does Adsense account differ from AdMob account?
4. Do I need to open both Admob and then Adsense account? Do they charge for using their service?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.) You need not to have Admob account with same gmail account. Just create an Admob account with any gmail id and then create ad units inside that. Note the ad unit id and use that id in your application. The amount that you will earn through that ad unit will be displayed in your admob account, it has nothing to do with the account from which you are hosting the app on playstore.

2.) Yes, until your application is not published, it will show you test ads on your emulator, but you should distribute your application to your friends etc.. after publishing it on google play. Please also read instructions on google admobs, there are various possible reason through which they can block your admob account for 30 days, so you should be aware of that.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: i should create ad unit id by selecting **Add app manually** option, for unpublish app, right?

Comment: You should select the app and create ad manually, name it something which you can recognize later. Get the ad unit id, using that ad unit id create an adview in your application.

Comment: They do not charge to signing up. Are you googling before posting on stack overflow? See this link it is mentioned clearly about adsense and admob. https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2784575?hl=en

Comment: So, first I need to create Adsense account with any gmail account and then use the same gmail account  for openning the Admob account?

Comment: You need to create a adsense account and note its publisher id and use that id while creating admob account. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help!